# how to extract text from scanned pdf file using java

Tags: java, itext, tesseract, pdfbox, pdftotext

I have manually scanned some hard copy files and stored into pdf files(soft copy).Now these pdf files are my input, so I need to extract text from these pdf files. I tried tika,pdfbox,itext,tess4j nothing is giving atlease 50% accuracy(mostly getting junk data) for my files(getting exact text for other pdf's downloaded from internet), can u suggest me a solution for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Try improving the quality of your scan keep it above 300 dpi for OCR, remove noise from it.

Comment: As far as using iText you have to have the pdf version, not scanned pdf, It will not give you any data. The file should be pdf.

Comment: Most of the libraries you mentioned only extract text which already is present in the PDF as textual content, not as a mere image. Thus, they depend on your former ocr'ing. So, how did you apply ocr to the PDF?

Comment: It's true that extracting text directly from PDF only works when the file is document-based and contains text. If it's a scanned document with only images, converting to text requires OCR. Since this was posted 3 years ago, new options have become available. There's now a good Java OCR engine that works under Windows, Android and Linux that's part of [the LEADTOOLS SDKs](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/java) Disclaimer: I'm an employee of this company.